# Shifting a 2D array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

I have a 2d array looking like this:

```
values = new int[11, 11] {
        { 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20},
        { 00, 20, 20, 20, 00, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20},
        { 00, 00, 20, 20, 00, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20},
        { 20, 20, 20, 20, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 20},
        { 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 00, 20},
        { 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 00, 20},
        { 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 00, 00, 00, 00, 20},
        { 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 00, 20, 20, 20, 20},
        { 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 00, 20, 20, 20, 20},
        { 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00},
        { 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00},
    };
```

Now I need to shift all layers by 1 down but all the rows need to stay the same. The layer at the bottom needs to be deleted and at the top a new layer needs to be created with all values 0. The result should look like this:

```
values = new int[11, 11] {
    { 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00},
    { 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20},
    { 00, 20, 20, 20, 00, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20},
    { 00, 00, 20, 20, 00, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20},
    { 20, 20, 20, 20, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 20},
    { 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 00, 20},
    { 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 00, 20},
    { 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 00, 00, 00, 00, 20},
    { 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 00, 20, 20, 20, 20},
    { 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 00, 20, 20, 20, 20},
    { 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00},
};
```

I tried to code a function using for loops to do this. But didn't succeed. This is one attempt for doing it:

```
for(int row = 11; row > 0; row--) {
    for(int col = 0; col < 11; col++) {
        targets[row, col] = targets[row + 1, col]; 
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this is the only attempt I still have.
Can anyone please help me do this or has a finished function to do this?

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: can you please ***share*** the code you've written, and ***how*** it didn't succeed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [Array.Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?view=netcore-3.1#System_Array_Copy_System_Array_System_Int64_System_Array_System_Int64_System_Int64_), it will work with the contiguous memory of a multi-dimensional array

> Copies a range of elements from an Array starting at the specified
> source index and pastes them to another Array starting at the
> specified destination index. The length and the indexes are specified
> as 64-bit integers.

```
Array.Copy(values,0, values,1, values.GetLength(0)* values.GetLength(1)-1);
```

[Full Demo Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2qaRTo)

**Update**

> Sorry I used the wrong words. The layers need to be shifted one down
> but the rows must stay the same.

Then, you just need to do the math

```
Array.Copy(values,0, values, values.GetLength(0)+1, values.GetLength(0) * values.GetLength(1) -values.GetLength(0)-1);

// Zero out the first row
Array.Copy(new int[values.GetLength(0)+1,1],0,values , 0,values.GetLength(0)+1);
```

[Full Demo Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/N4VZYB)

Comment: Sorry I used the wrong words. The layers need to be shifted one down but the rows must stay the same.